# Xml Deserialization Fails on Empty Element

Tags: c#, xml, exception, serialization

I have an Xml document that looks similar too

```
<Reports xmlns="">
  <Report>
    <ReportID>1</ReportID>
    <ParameterTemplate />
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

It fails serializing to this object

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Report")]
public class Report
{
    [XmlElement("ReportID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ParameterTemplate")]
    public XElement ParameterTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

It's failing because the empty ParameterTemplate element, because if it contains child elements it deserializes fine.

How can I get this to work?

This is my Deserialization Code

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
return (Report)serializer.Deserialize(source.CreateReader());
```

The exception is

> The XmlReader must be on a node of type Element instead of a node of type EndElement.

How can I get this to deserialize with the existing xml?

Thanks
-c

Comment: Out of interest, does it work fine if it's `<ParameterTemplate></ParameterTemplate>` ?

Comment: No, but removing it completely does allow it to serialize.

Comment: what exactly do you want to store inside a `XElement` in your XML file then?? Seems a bit odd.....

Comment: @marc_s, it is more XML, but it's not 'strongly typed' like the rest of the XML file is.  It's not even required if the report has no parameters.

Comment: Why not just add [XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]

Comment: @Dan, because it's not null.  And I tried it and it didn't work :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the content of `XElement` - if *not* null - cannot be an empty XML element. In other words, you would not be able to serialize *that* XML in your example from an in-memory representation/instance of your `Report` class.

Comment: That's the conclusion I've come to, I've talked to the provider of that XML to remove null elements

Comment: This looks like a symptom of not serializing the XML correctly in the first case, which is most likely done with .NET 1.0 XmlSerializer. To correctly serialize `minOccurs="0"` elements (e.g. elements that shouldn't exist in the XML), you need a `bool ParameterTemplateSpecified` element in the class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330001/xml-serialization-render-empty-element/2541396#2541396

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IXmlSerializable` interface on your report class and overwrite ReadXml and WriteXml methods.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following method to patch the XML text:

```
Public Function XMLReaderPatch(rawXML As String) As String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawXML) Then Return rawXML

     'Pattern for finding items similar to <name*/> where * may represent whitespace followed by text and/or whitespace
     Dim pattern As String = "<(\S+)(\s[^<|>]*)?/>"
     'Pattern for replacing with items similar to <name*></name> where * may represent whitespace followed by text and/or whitespace
     Dim replacement As String = "<$1$2></$1>"
     Dim rgx As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)

     Return rgx.Replace(rawXML, replacement)
 End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Use IsNullable=True

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Report")]
public class Report
{
    [XmlElement("ReportID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ParameterTemplate", IsNullable=true)]
    public XElement ParameterTemplate { get; set; }
}
```