# Xml Serialization - Render Empty Element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using the XmlSerializer and have the following property in a class

```
public string Data { get; set; }
```

which I need to be output exactly like so

```
<Data />
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution to this was to create a `PropertyNameSpecified` property that the serializer uses to determine whether to serialize the property or not. For example:

```
public string Data { get; set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public bool DataSpecified 
{ 
   get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data); }
   set { return; } //The serializer requires a setter
}
```

Answer (score 34):

I was recently doing this and there is an alternative way to do it, that seems a bit simpler. You just need to initialise the value of the property to an empty string then it will create an empty tag as you required;

```
Data = string.Empty;
```

Comment: For strings, this worked like a charm! If Data is never assigned a value, it will be present in the XML as `<Data />` and without the xsi:nil="true" attribute either.

Answer (score 3):

try to use **public bool ShouldSerialize_PropertyName_(){}** with setting the default value inside.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeData()
{
   Data = Data ?? "";
   return true;
}
```

Description of why this works can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I stand corrected. Added a link to relevant documentation so others don't make the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the XMLElementAttribute like [XmlElement(IsNullable=true)] to that member and also set in the get/set property something like this:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] 
public string Data 
{ 
    get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.data) ? string.Empty : this.data; } 
    set 
    { 
        if (this.data != value) 
        { 
            this.data = value; 
        } 
    } 
} 
private string data;
```

And so you will not have:

```
<Data xsi:nil="true" />
```

You will have this on render:

```
<Data />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the XMLElementAttribute like `[XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]` to that member. That will force the XML Serializer to add the element even if it is null.

Comment: But won't this render <Data xsi:nil="true" />

Answer (score 0):

We've just had this issue with the Microsoft Group Policy XML format that does things in a strange way storing each day of the week a schedule runs as an empty XML Element.

I agree with Jaimal Chohan's method - you can snazzy it up a bit and make it more friendly with the PropertyGrid by making the backing String variable readonly and then setting it to null or an empty string based on the user accessible boolean variable.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The schedule days.
    /// </summary>
    public class ScheduleDays:GlobalSerializableBase
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Monday backing variable.
        /// </summary>
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [XmlElement("Monday")]
        public String MondayString
        {
            get { return _MondayString; }
            set { _MondayString = value; }
        }
        private String _MondayString = null;


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets whether the schedule runs on Monday.
        /// </summary>
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool Monday
        {
            get { return MondayString != null ; }
            set { MondayString = value ? String.Empty : null; }
        }


    }



}
```