# Removing empty space from closing XML tag

Tags: c#, xml, sepa

Below is a code snippet of creating a document:

```
CdtrAcct = new CdtrAcct
{
    Id = new Id
    {
        IBAN = iban,
        Othr = new Othr
        {
            Id = creditBankAcct
        },
    },
},
```

If the IBAN field has a value, then Id is null. However, when the XML file is formed, I get the below:

```
<CdtrAcct>
  <Id>
    <IBAN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
    <Othr />
  </Id>
</CdtrAcct>
```

The problem that I have is that the software that reads the XML cannot process the whitespace here: `<Othr />`. What do I need to do to get `<Othr/>`?

C# code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));                               
var textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\BankFiles\Outbox\" + filename + ".xml"); 
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, config);
textWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Fix that other buggy software. Whitespace isn't significant in XML. There's no difference between `<Othr />`, `<Othr/>` or `<Othr></Othr>`. Use any XML validator you want, what you posted is perfectly valid XML.

Comment: @Panagiotis, I cannot fix the other software, it is a bank consuming this XML and I just send them outgoing payment info through XML.

Comment: Tell them they have a bug. No bank can change the definition of XML. If they signed a contract asking for XML, they're obliged to accept XML. If not, they're violating their own contract. If they want to change the contract to accept their own custom text format, they should change the contract, make that explicit and pay the cost.

Comment: It's very easy for banks to fix buggy software once contracts and lawyers are involved or even mentioned. They can't even make any claims about XML - it's an international standard and all XML validators will accept this XML string.

Comment: Try to create a class definition
.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330001/xml-serialization-render-empty-element

Comment: @swagatraorane: The OP already *has* a class - it's in the question. I fail to see how the linked question is relevant to the formatting of self-closing elements.

Comment: They can't claim that .NET has a bug either - .NET supports XML serialization since 2000. All banks use it. In fact, `XmlSerializer` is the oldest XML class, available since 2000.

Comment: @swagat the class definition is already in place.

Comment: @Panagiotis, I have just contacted the bank and will wait for a reply about this issue.

Comment: You can customize XML output with the [Serialize overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize?view=net-7.0#system-xml-serialization-xmlserializer-serialize(system-xml-xmlwriter-system-object)|) accepting an XmlWriter. You can create an XmlWriter with custom settings over a stream with [XmlWriter.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create?view=net-7.0) but [none of the settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-7.0) affects whitespace inside elements

Comment: It's quite possible the bank *doesn't* require`<Othr/>`. That's probably what the technical writer that created the CFP, contract or documentation used. Did you send an XML doc *with* whitespace that got rejected? If the bank's specs include an XSD schema, every validator will accept your document whether it contains trailing whitespace or not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos These are tests that a bank employee is asking to send to him before we get to send these files through some URL/port that will be provided later. Like I said, the personnel are the ones that said the whitespace is causing an issue.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau ask them for actual reproducible validation errors. If there's a real issue, they can find an online validator that actually rejects your XML message. Given how many hundreds of thousands of banks have used XML and .NET in the past 20+ years, they shouldn't have any problem finding an actual example .... unless they're dead wrong. Which they are.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau there may be a *different* error but the person reporting it misunderstood what it is. Perhaps `<Othr/>` isn't meant to be empty, or it's meant to have some required attributes. That's why you need the actual validation error, not just a "didn't work".

Comment: In your code `Othr` contains an `Id` element with the contents of `creditBankAcct`. In the XML you posted that's missing. Is *that* the real error perhaps? That the required `Id` element is missing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They reported having a problem with all tags such as this one. This is just one example. Payment data as you know varies so some fields will have certain info, some will not.

Comment: XML doesn't vary. The XML definition doesn't change because a bank says so. The file may be failing for other reasons though, eg you can't have both an IBAN and `Othr`. Is this a SEPA payments file? If you google for `SEPA CdtrAcct Othr` you'll find examples with empty `Othr` fields, or `Othr` fields with an `Id` and other elements.

Comment: Looking at the [SEPA specs](https://www.europeanpaymentscouncil.eu/sites/default/files/kb/file/2022-06/EPC121-16%20SCT%20Inst%20C2PSP%20IG%202023%20V1.0.pdf) and the corresponding [ISO 20022 fields](https://www.iso20022.org/iso-20022-message-definitions?url=https%3A//www.iso20022.org/iso-20022-message-definitions%3Fsearch%3DOthr&page=0) for `CustomerCreditTransferInitiationV11` I see that `Othr` is a `GenericAccountIdentification1` type that needs an `Id`. Is *that* the error perhaps? Have you tried validating your XML with the appropriate message XSD?

Comment: If you want to omit the `Othr` element set the `Othr` property to `null`, not the `Othr.Id` property.

Comment: Big organisations are often the worst when it comes to standards compliance because (a) they think they have the muscle to set their own rules, (b) making small changes to their software costs them a fortune because of overweight processes, and (c) their programmers are often rather inward-looking.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the XML to a string (e.g. `myString`), then you can replace `" \>"` with `"\>"` by using

```
myString.Replace(" \>", "\>");
```

Afterwards you can print it into a file.

Of course this is a workaround / hack and getting the buggy software fixed should be the first try. However, this should solve your problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid processing XML with anything other than a conformant XML parser.

But if you're stuck with it, it's easy enough to put the XML through an identity transformation that re-serializes it without the whitespace.

Comment: Unless the problem is the actual node content. The names are distinctive and googling brings up SEPA payments and field definitions. There are XSDs for those message types. The assignment `Id = creditBankAcct` suggests  `creditBankAcct` is null itself. I suspect the OP needs to set `Other` to null, not just the Id property